# SwiftUI: Apply a linear gradient to a shape using a Custom Class

Tags: swiftui, shapes, linear-gradients

How do I apply a linear gradient with a custom class that I made on a shape? For some reason it is not working for me. The foregroundColor is not working for me.

```
  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 1.01, height:geometry.size.height * 0.23)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(12), anchor: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(LinearGradient (gradient: Gradient(colors:[Color(ColorsSaved.gitLabDark),Color(ColorsSaved.gitLabLight)]),startPoint: .leading,endPoint: .trailing))
```

I created my CustomClass in a Swift file. Please see code below for that.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct ColorsSaved {
static let gitLabDark = UIColor( red: 0.12, green: 0.08, blue: 0.22, alpha: 1.0)
static let gitLabLight = UIColor( red: 0.26, green: 0.2, blue: 0.44, alpha: 1.0)
static let neonGreen =  UIColor(red: 0.497, green: 0.738, blue: 0.35, alpha: 1)
static let darkGreenTorquise = UIColor(red: 0.242, green: 0.683, blue: 0.577, alpha: 1)
static let brightOrange =   UIColor(red: 0.917, green: 0.469, blue: 0.218, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your intention, I would go with the following approach.

Result demo:
[image: SwiftUI shape with gradient]

Code:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    LinearGradient(gradient: 
          Gradient(colors:
             [Color(ColorsSaved.gitLabDark), Color(ColorsSaved.gitLabLight)]), 
          startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 1.01, height:geometry.size.height * 0.23)
    .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(12), anchor: .center)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Gradient`s in **SwiftUI** are supposed to be added with the help of `ZStack`. As you haven't added much code in your question I made my assumptions. Try this in your custom view:

```
struct WelcomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.pink, .purple]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            // here goes your other view component
            Text("Welcome, John")
        }
    }
}
```